# Why are my for loops ignoring elements that satisfy conditions?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, priority-queue

I sorted a list of passengers but some of them are not in their appropriate groups.

I'm using this criteria:

1st Group: Type H
2nd Group: Type E AND Row 1-4
3rd Group: Type G AND Row 1-4
4th Group: Type E OR (Type G AND Row 10 or 11)
5th Group: Type G AND Row 23-26
6th Group: Type G AND Row 17-22
7th Group: Type G AND Row 11-16
8th Group: Type G AND Row 5-10

The 1st group has should appear at the beginning of the list and 8th Group should appear at end of the list. The Priority numbers range from 103 to 1.

Here is the original unsorted list of passengers (Name, type, rowNumber):

```
Whitley G 8
Knowles G 1
Rocha G 24
Boyle G 24
Wooten G 2
Forbes G 16
Vinson E 1
Valencia E 7
Lindsay E 16
Rasmussen E 5
Sargent G 11
Sosa G 23
Head G 3
Holcomb G 5
Carney G 4
Kirkland G 14
Levine E 9
Cash G 10
Kaufman G 6
Ratliff G 9
Macias G 4
Sharpe G 17
Sweet G 17
Delaney G 9
Emerson G 5
Castaneda E 9
Rutledge G 26
Stuart G 19
Rosales G 23
Baird G 2
Clemons G 8
Mcgowan G 18
Compton E 10
Albert G 15
Acevedo G 14
Mayer E 9
Fitzpatrick G 16
Chaney G 8
Jarvis G 3
Berger G 26
Britt E 11
Odonnell E 8
Levy E 9
Mullen G 6
Pollard G 22
Lott G 10
Cantrell G 15
Holder E 5
Vaughan E 11
Mccarty E 24
Wilder G 11
Mayo G 1
Pickett G 8
Sykes G 26
Bender G 13
Aguirre G 16
Bernard G 10
Hopper H 7
Melendez G 13
Macdonald H 18
Carver G 15
Gould E 26
Suarez G 6
Zamora G 15
Hinton G 13
Cabrera G 26
Dickson G 22
Salas G 24
Bentley G 13
Fuentes G 23
Terrell H 3
Holman E 7
Mcintyre G 16
Hebert G 13
Hendricks G 3
Jacobson G 14
Kline G 14
Faulkner G 5
Chan G 14
Mays G 1
Crosby G 25
Buck G 22
Maddox G 20
Buckley E 17
Kane G 10
Rivas E 26
Dudley G 22
Best G 12
Finley G 24
William G 18
Frost G 2
Ashley G 14
Mcconnell G 7
Blevins G 11
Middleton G 17
Bean G 18
Sheppard G 11
Estes E 7
Pugh G 8
Rivers E 6
Barr G 4
Landry E 10
Foley G 2
```

Here is my some of my code:

```
public void loadOldPQ(ArrayList<Passenger> list) throws IOException {
    
    int priorityNumber = list.size();

    while (!list.isEmpty()) {
        //H forLoop capture all required passengers
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("H")) {
                list.get(i).setKey(priorityNumber);
                oldPQ.add((list.get(i)));
                list.remove(i);
                priorityNumber--;
            }
        }

        //Type E AND Row 1-4 forLoop works
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list.get(j).getRow() >= 1 && list.get(j).getRow() <= 4
                    && list.get(j).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("E")) {
                list.get(j).setKey(priorityNumber);
                oldPQ.add(list.get(j));
                list.remove(j);
                priorityNumber--;
            }
        }

        //Type G(implied) and Row 1-4 forLoop works
        for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++) {
            if (list.get(k).getRow() >= 1 && list.get(k).getRow() <= 4) {

                list.get(k).setKey(priorityNumber);
                oldPQ.add(list.get(k));
                list.remove(k);
                priorityNumber--;
            }
        }

        //Type E or Row 10, 11 forLoop
        for (int l = 0; l < list.size(); l++) {
            if (list.get(l).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("E") || list.get(l).getRow() == 10
                    || list.get(l).getRow() == 11) {
                list.get(l).setKey(priorityNumber);
                oldPQ.add(list.get(l));
                list.remove(l);
                priorityNumber--;
            }
        }

        //Row 23-26 forLoop
        for (int m = 0; m < list.size(); m++) {
            if (list.get(m).getRow() >= 23 && list.get(m).getRow() <= 26) {
                list.get(m).setKey(priorityNumber);
                oldPQ.add(list.get(m));
                list.remove(m);
                priorityNumber--;
            }
        }

        //Row 17-22 forLoop
        for (int n = 0; n < list.size(); n++) {
            if (list.get(n).getRow() >= 17 && list.get(n).getRow() <= 22) {
                list.get(n).setKey(priorityNumber);
                oldPQ.add(list.get(n));
                list.remove(n);
                priorityNumber--;
            }
        }

        //Row 11-16 forLoop (row 11 should've already been removed)
        for (int o = 0; o < list.size(); o++) {
            if (list.get(o).getRow() >= 11 && list.get(o).getRow() <= 16) {
                list.get(o).setKey(priorityNumber);
                oldPQ.add(list.get(o));
                list.remove(o);
                priorityNumber--;
            }
        }

        //Row 5-10 forLoop (Row 10 passengers should've already be removed)
        for (int p = 0; p < list.size(); p++) {
            if (list.get(p).getRow() >= 5 && list.get(p).getRow() <= 10) {
                list.get(p).setKey(priorityNumber);
                oldPQ.add(list.get(p));
                list.remove(p);
                priorityNumber--;
            }
        }
    }
    oldProcedure(oldPQ);
}
```

For instance, Kane, McConnell, Estes should be group with 4th group. Clemons, Chauncy, Pickett should appear towards the end of the list in 8th Group because they have row numbers 5-10.

Here are my results:

```
Name           Type Row  Key  

Hopper         H    7    103  
Macdonald      H    18   102  
Terrell        H    3    101  
Vinson         E    1    100  
Knowles        G    1    99   
Wooten         G    2    98   
Head           G    3    97   
Carney         G    4    96   
Macias         G    4    95   
Baird          G    2    94   
Jarvis         G    3    93   
Mayo           G    1    92   
Hendricks      G    3    91   
Mays           G    1    90   
Frost          G    2    89   
Barr           G    4    88   
Foley          G    2    87   
Valencia       E    7    86   
Rasmussen      E    5    85   
Levine         E    9    84   
Castaneda      E    9    83   
Compton        E    10   82   
Mayer          E    9    81   
Britt          E    11   80   
Levy           E    9    79   
Lott           G    10   78   
Holder         E    5    77   
Mccarty        E    24   76   
Bernard        G    10   75   
Gould          E    26   74   
Holman         E    7    73   
Buckley        E    17   72   
Rivas          E    26   71   
Blevins        G    11   70   
Sheppard       G    11   69   
Rivers         E    6    68   
Rocha          G    24   67   
Sosa           G    23   66   
Rutledge       G    26   65   
Rosales        G    23   64   
Berger         G    26   63   
Sykes          G    26   62   
Cabrera        G    26   61   
Salas          G    24   60   
Fuentes        G    23   59   
Crosby         G    25   58   
Finley         G    24   57   
Sharpe         G    17   56   
Stuart         G    19   55   
Mcgowan        G    18   54   
Pollard        G    22   53   
Dickson        G    22   52   
Buck           G    22   51   
Dudley         G    22   50   
William        G    18   49   
Middleton      G    17   48   
Forbes         G    16   47   
Sargent        G    11   46   
Kirkland       G    14   45   
Albert         G    15   44   
Fitzpatrick    G    16   43   
Cantrell       G    15   42   
Wilder         G    11   41   
Bender         G    13   40   
Melendez       G    13   39   
Zamora         G    15   38   
Bentley        G    13   37   
Hebert         G    13   36   
Kline          G    14   35   
Chan           G    14   34   
Best           G    12   33   
Whitley        G    8    32   
Holcomb        G    5    31   
Kaufman        G    6    30   
Delaney        G    9    29   
Clemons        G    8    28   
Chaney         G    8    27   
Mullen         G    6    26   
Pickett        G    8    25   
Suarez         G    6    24   
Faulkner       G    5    23   
Kane           G    10   22   
Mcconnell      G    7    21   
Estes          E    7    20   
Landry         E    10   19   
Lindsay        E    16   18   
Odonnell       E    8    17   
Boyle          G    24   16   
Sweet          G    17   15   
Maddox         G    20   14   
Bean           G    18   13   
Acevedo        G    14   12   
Aguirre        G    16   11   
Hinton         G    13   10   
Jacobson       G    14   9    
Cash           G    10   8    
Emerson        G    5    7    
Pugh           G    8    6    
Vaughan        E    11   5    
Carver         G    15   4    
Ashley         G    14   3    
Ratliff        G    9    2    
Mcintyre       G    16   1
```

Comment: Could you... list the actual priority criteria you're trying to implement? This algorythm is terrible and I have a couple of ideas why it's not doing what you want, but for a proper answer it would be good to know what you do want to do. should E row 5 go before or after G row 1 for instance? Does it matter if E row 3 has lower priority than E row 1?

Comment: I haven't yet looked closely at this. But, problems like this are sometimes caused by altering a `Collection` while iterating through it. Try changing `for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++)` to `for (int x = list.size() - 1; x <= 0; x--)` and see if that makes a difference. Substitute for `x` the appropriate variable name.

Comment: Even if that is the problem, my suggestion might not work. You should get and use an `Iterator` for altering a `Collection` while iterating through it.

Comment: @Deltharis My bad. I just edited the post to include the original list of passengers to be sorted.  The criteria is basically boarding passengers based on their Key. From highest to lowest.

Comment: "Key" is not an input parameter, that's what your algorythm generates, this is not an answer. If your goal was sorting by Key than you have succeeded, your results are indeed sorted by Key.

Answer (score 1):

Run this little program and you'll understand that removing items without adjusting the index means that you skip items:

```java
class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));

        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i) {
            System.out.println("Checking " + l.get(i));
            if ("B".equals(l.get(i))) {
                l.remove(i);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You need to decrement `i` after removing an item, i.e.

```
...
            if ("B".equals(l.get(i))) {
                l.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
...
```

Alternatively, use an `Iterator`, as Old Dog suggested:

```
class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
        Iterator<String> i = l.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            String s = i.next();
            System.out.println("Checking " + s);
            if ("B".equals(s)) {
                i.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're doing your assignment correctly? You get a list of `Passenger`s. You are supposed to put them on a priority queue (which I'm going to assume is `java.util.PriorityQueue`), to have them sorted according to some rules. `Passenger` implements `Comparable`.

The most natural way to approach it, would be to implement the `compareTo()` method in `Passenger` properly with the sorting rules - so that you can just put the passengers onto the queue and have the sorting happen without any extra code.

```
public class Passenger implements Comparable<Passenger>{

    public Passenger(int row, String name, String type) {
        this.row = row;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Passenger o) {
        if(this.getKey() > o.getKey()) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(this.getKey() < o.getKey()){
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private int getKey(){
        if(type.equals("H"){
            return 8;
        } else if (type.equals("E") && row <= 4){
            return 7;
        } else 
        ... // implement all your groups criteria like this
    }
}
```

So changing key to be just an internal method that knows your sorting requirements. Then your method simplifies to just

```
public void loadOldPQ(ArrayList<Passenger> list) throws IOException {
    oldPQ.addAll(list);
}
```

And PriorityQueue does it's job sorting them out for you.